Буква, которая обозначает и гласный, и согласный звук?
Буква, которая обозначает и гласный, и согласный звук? Вопрос с муниципального этапа всош.

Обычное предложение не станет вопросительным, если к нему добавить знак вопроса. Вопрос надо сформулировать.

Может это "У"? При транслитерации английских имён собственных вроде "Уиллис" она обозначает обозначает либо звонкий лабиовелярный аппроксимант [w] как в английском, либо просто [в']. В любом случае в этой позиции реализуется согласный звук.
Или, например, "И" — на стыке слов в беглой речи "кои-то веки" можно произносить как [f kɪj tə ˈvʲekʲɪ]

Может, "ё"? Это же два звука одновременно (/jo/ в МФА).

Если Ё, тогда надо добавить Е, Ю и Я.

А, точно, тогда не знаю)

Может, в вопросе были варианты ответов, чтобы выбрать именно одну букву. Это надо у Амины уточнять... А так, я думаю, ваш ответ в принципе верный, только дополнить бы.

Скорее всего Й, или "и краткое"
